# Virtual terminal for USB-C serial port adapter on iPhone 15?

Tags: iphone, usb

I have a USB-C to RS232 adapter cable that obviously physically fits into the USB-C port on an iPhone 15 Pro. Is there any virtual terminal app to communicate with a device on the other end of the serial line? I occasionally use [Prompt](https://panic.com/prompt/) for SSH, but it doesn't have a way for me to select a local serial port.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I too am interested in connecting USB UART / Serial devices and communicating via a Terminal app like PuTTY but on iOS.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is as far as I’ve made it.